# JSON Schema: Combine multiple references

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

My Json Schema

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    
  "definitions": {
    
    "userInfo": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "firstName": { "type": "string" },
        "lastName":  { "type": "string" },
        "emailAddress":{ "type": "string" }
      },
      "required": ["firstName", "lastName", "emailAddress"]
    },
    
    "userPassword": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "password": { "type": "string" },
        "confirmPassword":  { "type": "string" }
      }
    }
  },

  "type": "object",
    
  "properties": {
    "standaloneDeveloper": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/userInfo",
      "$ref": "#/definitions/userPassword"
    } 
  }
}
```

Data is always getting overwritten with **#/definitions/userPassword**

I am getting the following output with this schema

```
{
  "standaloneDeveloper": {
    "password": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABC",
    "confirmPassword": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABC"
  }
}
```

Expected output

```
{
  "standaloneDeveloper": {
    "firstName": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABC",
    "lastName": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABC",
    "emailAddress": "ABCDEFGHI",
    "password": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABC",
    "confirmPassword": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABC"
  }
}
```

How can I combine userInfo and userPassword?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In JSON (and therefore JSON Schema as well) you can't have duplicate property names. You can use `allOf` to get around this.

```
"properties": {
  "standaloneDeveloper": {
    "allOf": [
      { "$ref": "#/definitions/userInfo" },
      { "$ref": "#/definitions/userPassword" }
    ]
  }
}
```

This way each object has only one `$ref` in it.